# Excel left formula shows an error (Not trying to type a formula)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a simple formula that I have found on the internet which does exactly what I want

```
=LEFT(K3,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A3&"0123456789"))-1)
```

the thing I found it on multiple sites and they said it works but when I used it excel gives me the following error

```
Not trying to type a formula?

When the first character is an equal (=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula:


• you type:   =1+1, cell shows:   2


To get around this, type an apostrophe ( ' ) first:


• you type:   '=1+1, cell shows:   =1+
```

may I know why and how to fix that?

my Excel version is 16.30

Comment: I could well be wrong, but i think you need an additional set of brackets starting after MIN and finishing after -1?

Comment: What are your windows regional settings?  You may need to use the semicolon in place of the commas to separate the formula arguments.

Comment: @AlexRobinson you are wrong. What would `MIN((` accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Your formula works fine for me,

If `A3` is 2 characters in length, it returns the first 2 characters of `K3`,

Is this the intended behavior ?

If this is what the formula should be doing, try replacing `,` with `;` like below:

```
=LEFT(K3;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A3&"0123456789"))-1)
```